# get the file names list by another list

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python and felt some kind of confused...
I have a List like:

```
List_all = ["aawoobbcc", "aawoobbca", "aabbcskindd","asakindsbbss","wooedakse","sdadakindwsd","xxxxsdsd"]
```

and also a keyword list:

```
Key = ["woo","kind"]
```

and I want to get something like this:

```
[
["aawoobbcc", "aawoobbca","wooedakse"],
["aabbcskindd","asakindsbbss","sdadakindwsd"]
]
```

I have tried `list_sub = [file for file in List_all if Key in file]`
or `list_sub = [file for file in List_all if k for k in Key in file]`
which were not right.

how could I go through the elements in Key for the substring of elements in List?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One approach (`O(n^2)`), is the following:

```
res = [[e for e in List_all if k in e] for k in Key]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['aawoobbcc', 'aawoobbca', 'wooedakse'], ['aabbcskindd', 'asakindsbbss', 'sdadakindwsd']]
```

A simpler to understand solution (for newbies) is to use nested *for* loops:

```
res = []
for k in Key:
    filtered = []
    for e in List_all:
        if k in e:
            filtered.append(e)
    res.append(filtered)
```

A more advanced solution, albeit more performant (for really long lists), is to use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) in conjunction with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

List_all = ["aawoobbcc", "aawoobbca", "aabbcskindd", "asakindsbbss", "wooedakse", "sdadakindwsd", "xxxxsdsd"]
Key = ["woo", "kind"]

extract_key = re.compile(f"{'|'.join(Key)}")
table = defaultdict(list)
for word in List_all:
    if match := extract_key.search(word):
        table[match.group()].append(word)

res = [table[k] for k in Key if k in table]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['aawoobbcc', 'aawoobbca', 'wooedakse'], ['aabbcskindd', 'asakindsbbss', 'sdadakindwsd']]
```

Note that this solution consider that each string contains only one key.

Comment: I see, so this requires two loops, which can't be put under the same level, thanks!